# Using SQLGeometry to display an item location on a floor plan in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sqlgeometry

Inventory items have a location field corresponding to a physical warehouse location i.e. item X location field states 'A01' corresponds to shelf location A01.
How can I leverage this data to display item locations on a floor plan of the warehouse?
Perhaps in the form of an SSRS report query for item X displaying the location on the floor plan?
I've searched around and seen that this [can be done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335706.aspx):

> "To start with the simplest case, suppose you’d like a map of the
>   layout of your company’s warehouse (a physical warehouse where goods
>   are stored, not a data warehouse). You’d likely measure the warehouse,
>   draw a floor plan, and map the placement of the goods based on their
>   location in the floor plan."

But I cannot find steps on how to achieve this. Any help in this regard appreciated.

Currently using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

It begins with your warehouse location data. Do you have the geometries of the warehouse and shelving stored in a table? If not, that is where you need to start. One corner of the building floor will be at coordinate 0 0. for example, if the building was a 1000 unit square, it would be a geometry such as:

```
POLYGON((0 0, 0 1000, 1000 1000, 1000 0, 00))
```

Data collection is not very easily done by using a floor plan. Usually CAD dwg files can be converted to standard GIS data and imported into sql server. Otherwise, you could digitize it using one of the many GIS software packages.

Once you have location information for the building and all the shelving units etc., you would simply join the item to the shelving unit and display the geometry of the shelving unit over the basemap of the warehouse.